# How to check that id references are valid using xPath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm beginner with xml, xsl and xPath. I would like to know how to check that all my refid attributes are valid?

In other words, I would like to have a xPath 1.0 query that returns TRUE if every refid attribute has a matching ID attribute (with same value of course). All products doesn't necessary have the ref node.

For example: if cookie points to bread AND bread points to milk AND milk poists to cookie THEN return TRUE, otherwise FALSE.

I've been trying to solve this and searched web for good example without luck. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my XML:

```
<shop>
 <product>
    <cookie ID="01">
    <price>2</price>
    </cookie>
    <ref refid="02"/>
 </product>

  <product>
    <bread ID="02">
    <price>5</price>
    </bread>
    <ref refid="03"/>
 </product>

 <product>
   <milk ID="03">
   <price>2</price>
   </milk>
   <ref refid="01"/>
</product>

</shop>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all `@refid` attributes which do not have a matching `@id`.

```
//@refid[not(//@ID = .)]
```

If you count the results and compare this to zero, it will return `true` for valid input and `false` for broken references.

```
count(//@refid[not(//@ID = .)]) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very simple and working solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With the question being tagged as `xslt` as well as as `xpath` I dare to suggest an XSLT 1.0 approach using a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="id" match="product" use="*[1]/@ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//ref[not(key('id', @refid))]">FALSE</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>TRUE</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This actually helped me with something I was working on yesterday - not the same problem, but a simple solution I should have thought of myself. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up using the xPath solution but I will take a look at and try your answer as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `boolean()`. The following will return either `true` or `false`:

```
boolean(not(//@refid[not(.=//@ID)]))
```

XSLT example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="boolean(not(//@refid[not(.=//@ID)]))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`boolean()` could also be used in Martin's more efficient `xsl:key` version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="id" match="product" use="*[1]/@ID"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="boolean(not(//ref[not(key('id', @refid))]))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using boolean() looks very nice and compact. :)